# Cannot exit While loop

Tags: c++, while-loop, duration

I want to exit While loop, when variable "duration" reaches 5 sec.

Variable "duration" always =0

```
#include <iostream>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <chrono>

using namespace std;
DOUBLE duration;


int main()
{

    using clock = std::chrono::system_clock;
    using sec = std::chrono::duration <double>;
    const auto before = clock::now();
    while (duration < 5.0)     
    {
        const auto after = clock::now();
        const sec duration = after - before;
        std::cout << "It took " << duration.count() << "s" << std::endl;

    }
    std::cout << "After While Loop ";  //Never reaches this line!!!!!
    return 0;
}
```

Actual output:.
   .
   it took 9.50618s
   it tool 9.50642s
   .
   I expected while loop to exit at 5.0 or higher.

display variable always shows 0.

Comment: `duration` you are printing is local to that loop. While the `duration` you are checking in `while` loop is a different one

Comment: Your "actual output" does not look like it can be the output of the shown code.

Comment: Classic case of unnoticed [Variable shadowing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable_shadowing)

Comment: Thank Everybody.It works.

Answer (score 3):

You are using two separate variables named `duration`.

```
using sec = std::chrono::duration <double>; // number 1
const auto before = clock::now();
while (duration < 5.0) // checking number 1, which is not changed during looping    
{
    const auto after = clock::now();
    const sec duration = after - before; // number 2, created afresh in each iteration 
    std::cout << "It took " << duration.count() << "s" << std::endl;

}
```

So, what you are checking in the loop condition is not what gets changed in the loop body.

Answer (score 3):

You have two variables called duration:

```
DOUBLE duration;
```

and in while loop:

```
const sec duration = after - before;
```

During evaluation of `while` statement you are checking the first one that is never set or changed.
Inside `while` loop body you're creating a new variable that shadows global variable. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable_shadowing

Insead you shouldn't declare a new variable but use one declared before entering to the `while` loop.

Comment: Nice background link. (Sorry that I did not notice it earlier. You probably know what I mean...)

Answer (score 3):

There are two issues here:

1. Declaring a local variable with the same name that of the global variable makes them two separate entities, which may get quiet confusing. This phenomenon is called as [Variable shadowing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable_shadowing).
2. You are comparing the `duration` variable which is actually an **object** of class `sec` and **not an integer or float**. So, for comparing the value in `duration` just do `duration.count()` to make it comparable to integer or float values.

Here, in your code, the global `duration` variable is never changed because you are declaring a new variable inside the while loop. The `duration` variable that is been checked in the while condition is the global `duration` variable but you expect it to be the duration variable inside the loop.

There are two possible solutions:

1. Either make the two `duration` variables the same.
2. Or break the `while(1)` loop when the `duration` variable hold value `>= 5`,

Solution 1 code looks like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <chrono>

using namespace std;

int main()
{

    using clock = std::chrono::system_clock;
    using sec = std::chrono::duration <double>;
    sec duration;
    const auto before = clock::now();
    while (duration.count() < 5.0)
    {
        const auto after = clock::now();
        duration = after - before;
        std::cout << "It took " << duration.count() << "s" << std::endl;
    }
    std::cout << "After While Loop ";  //Never reaches this line!!!!!
    return 0;
}
```

Solution 2 code looks like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <chrono>

using namespace std;

int main()
{

    using clock = std::chrono::system_clock;
    using sec = std::chrono::duration <double>;
    const auto before = clock::now();
    while (1) // Soln 1: while(1)
    {
        const auto after = clock::now();
        const sec duration = after - before;
        std::cout << "It took " << duration.count() << "s" << std::endl;
        if(duration.count() >= 5) 
            break;
    }
    std::cout << "After While Loop ";  //Never reaches this line!!!!!
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: not given you the downvote but want to mention that in your code `sec duration;` line will create an compilation error as `sec` is defined later. Second is `duration` is an object and you are trying to compare with a float/double.

Comment: you missed the second issue I mentioned. `duration` in while loop (and if in 2nd solution) should be `duration.count()`